# UIPickerView setting int Variable

Tags: ios, variables, uipickerview

```
- (BOOL)setupAVCapture
{
 NSError *error = nil;

frameDuration = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1./5., 90000);

AVCaptureSession *session = [AVCaptureSession new];
[session setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh];
```

Thats my .m file for my Xcode Project. Can somebody please tell me if theres a way to use a UIpickerView or any way so that when running the app I can change the "5" to a different number in order to increase the frames per second. Please i've looked and theres no answer anywhere.

----UIPICKERVIEW CODE--

```
-(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, pickerView.frame.size.width, 33)];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-bold" size:36];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"  %ld", row+1];
    return label;
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [_list count];
}

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [_list objectAtIndex:row];

}

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Fps:%@", [_list objectAtIndex:row]];
    _pickerLabel.text = string;
}
```

---

```
-(void)Viewdidload

 _list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [_list addObject:@"  1"];
    [_list addObject:@"  2"];
    [_list addObject:@"  3"];
    [_list addObject:@"  4"];
    [_list addObject:@"  5"];
    [_list addObject:@"  6"];
    [_list addObject:@"  7"];
    [_list addObject:@"  8"];
    [_list addObject:@"  9"];
```

----------Frames-----

```
NSError *error = nil;

    frameDuration = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1./5., 90000);
```

Comment: Question title contains the answer: create an int variable that is set using a UIPickerView.  You couldn't find _any_ examples of coding a UIPickerView _anywhere_?

Comment: Xcode always shows an error whenever anything but a number is placed instead of the 5. I tried doing something like int = a; but whenever i place a instead of 5 it gives me an error

Comment: Edit your question and show the exact code that you tried and give the exact error that you got and on what line it gives the error.

Comment: Im not sure how to do it thats why im asking the question. Im new to Xcode. I have the UIpickerView displaying its number in a label but i dont know how to create a variable out of it and place it instead of the 5. Should i still display whatever other code i have set up for it?

Comment: Yes, show what you've tried and give the exact errors you get otherwise the question may get closed as "not clear what you're asking".  Just don't post too much code.  Narrow it down to the relevant parts.

Comment: Theres no error with this code but the UIpickerView doesnt change the .5 in the 1./5. so the frames stay 5 frames per second. Im trying to get it so that the the pickerviews # will change the .5 in the 1./.5 so that the user decides how many frames per sec the video will be

Comment: is there anything i can do?

Comment: You've done this much so I'm not sure why you're stuck on this.  Declare a float variable (eg. `float framesPerSecond;`) the same way you declared frameDuration.  In didSelectRow, set the float variable equal to row+1 (`framesPerSecond = row + 1;`).  In setupAVCapture, replace the "5." with the float variable.